# Privilege progress indicator interferes with (old) Stack Exchange dropdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, stack-exchange-button

I know I'm late with this; this could be the last bug report about the old topbar. But the text on the privilege progress indicator (on your profile page) appears *above* the dropdown menu coming from the Stack Exchange button, as can be seen in the picture below.

[image]

Changing the `z-index` property of `.s-progress-bar._badge .-info, .s-progress-bar._privilege .-info` from 2 to 1 solves the problem.

---

The new menu seems to have a high enough z-index so that this is no longer a problem anymore:

[image]

Comment: wait for 1 or 2 weeks and it will hit with a [tag:status-completed] when the new topbar rolled to all sites

Comment: @redhand that, or closed as 'can no longer be reproduced'.

Comment: @redhand that, or just ignored. o_O

Comment: @rene *Dear Next Person Who Opens a Z-Index 'Bug', I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death with a giant Z*.

Comment: @Glorfindel Oh dear,
 it's [me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301100/next-privilege-toolbar-showing-above-global-inbox-reputation-site-list?noredirect=1#comment979029_301100)

Comment: @boboquack apparently it's [me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301452/162102) now.

Comment: Happened with ["help" link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Uc5O.png) too.