# Next privilege toolbar showing above global inbox/reputation/site list

Tags: bug, reputation, design, profile-page, global-inbox

When I click global inbox, the reputation or the site list button on sites with the old toolbar, it shows below the outline and writing for the next privilege. Is this a problem as the new toolbar is being introduced? I haven't seen it before.

It happens across multiple sites and also after reloading on Windows 10 with Chrome 61.0.3163.91.

---

Images (click for higher quality versions)

Puzzling, site list:
[image: PSE+SL]

English, global inbox:
[image: ELU+GI]

Code Golf, reputation:
[image: PCG+R]