# Achievements drop-down has bleed-through on chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, design, achievements-dialog

This is new:

[image: dropdown doesn't fully obscure chat info]

I saw this earlier today in Firefox (current version) on Win 7, and I'm seeing it now in Chrome 61.0.3163.100 on Mac Sierra.  It only happens on chat info pages, not on Q&A sites.  I suspect there's a Z-order problem with those time labels on the chat pages.

The numbers are sticky by position; if I scroll the achievements pane those times overlap whatever is in that place in the pane.

Comment: Probably the same cause as [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301068/295232).

Comment: actually all of this are caused by the same evil **z-index** of dropdowns have lower value than that of page content

Comment: This is *not* a dupe of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301068/privilege-progress-indicator-interferes-with-old-stack-exchange-dropdown. I mean it sort of is, but the problem is technically with the thing that shines through, not with the popup, making it two different issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed now, I've told those numbers to stay in hiding.

Comment: My cat goes into hiding when I bring out the cat carrier.  I wonder what those numbers are afraid of, that you can use to keep them in hiding. :-)